# How to store entire raw request of an API in string variable using karate framework?

Tags: karate

In my project , will be sharing text file with request and response of an API.
i was unable to get how to access the entire raw request of an API using karate.
Please let me know if we can store the entire request in a string with all header values

Comment: could anyone please help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the "raw" request, you can get it via [`karate.prevRequest`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/226) - also search for it in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object

Comment: sorry, the question is - for response we will be storing as " And def a =response" in feature file for further usage  and for storing the request ,please let me know is there any inbuilt method to get the raw request ,so that we can create text log .